# Creating a WPF property grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

Where would I start looking, if I wanted to create my own property grid control in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

[WPF Property Grid](http://wpg.codeplex.com) as mentioned by @Pop Catalin is good, but is painful to use in an MVVM scenario; databinding only seems to work when the control first loads, once you try binding to another object, it fails. I ended up having to couple my view model to the view to retrieve the property grid and directly set the bound object. Blech!

A better free control is the one included in the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit); it handles the databinding much better, and visually it's nicer too, having picked up a lot of cues from VS 2010's property grid.

Comment: It is very feature rich as well. Able to create custom editors that target data types or property names or both.  You can also define editors in code with attributes or in XAML with dataTemplates.

Comment: The Extended WPF Toolkit is available for free only for non-commercial use: 
[License](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/license.md)

Comment: it does not answer the question about creating your own property grid